# Can payment from a P2SH address provide change to itself?

Tags: blockchain, multi-signature, p2sh

In the [gavinandresen Multisig Test](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3QJmV3qfvL9SuYo34YihAf3sRCW3qSinyC) test, could change have been redirected to the originating `3QJmV3qfvL9SuYo34YihAf3sRCW3qSinyC` P2SH address for the multisig payments?

In [Mastering Bitcoin by Andreas M. Antonopoulos, Chapter 5. Transactions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-bitcoin/9781491902639/ch05.html) the following statement is made, and I would like to know if it invalidate my question above: "*Note that you are not able to put a P2SH inside a P2SH redeem script, because the P2SH specification is not recursive.*"

Answer (score 2):

These two things are actually not related. There are no restrictions to address reuse in the protocol. You could get away with never using more than a single address ever (although that is not recommended especially for privacy reasons) and p2sh addresses are no exception there.

The `redeem script` encodes the conditions that have to be fulfilled in order to spend funds from an unspent transaction output (UTXO). What the sentence says, is that you cannot have a lock to another redeem script inside of a redeem script.